# How to declare a function in a function parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin, parameters, android-jetpack-compose

When creating a login page in a mobile application, I want my application screen function to be more transparent and legible by creating a repeating element with the same parameters. However, I encountered a problem creating it, because I can't declare `loginUiState?.password ?: ""` in the form of `value: String`. How do I make this feature work?

This is the part of my `Login.kt` code that I want to shorten.

```
OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(20.dp),
            value = loginUiState?.userName ?: "",
            onValueChange = {loginViewModel?.onUserNameChange(it)},
            leadingIcon = {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Email, contentDescription = null)
            },
            label = {
                Text(text = "Email")
            },
            isError = isEerror
        )
```

In the `Elements.ks` file I want to create a function containing `OutlinedTextField` whose input parameters I will be able to declare from `Login.ks`

Comment: "I can't declare" Why not?

Comment: I can but it doesn't work when parameter is :String

Comment: What do you mean by that? Which parameter? The `value` parameter of the `OutlinedTextField` function is defined as a String. Your above code looks correct. Maybe it will help communicate your issue if you show the code you're trying to write that won't compile.

Comment: Are you importing from import androidx.compose.material3.*? What is the type of `loginUiState?.userName`? What is the copy pasted version of the error you are getting?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.